# how to get only one record for each duplicate row of the id in datastage

Tags: sql, db2, etl, datastage

I have

```
**Table**

Name,RNo,M1,M2,M3,M4

Raj,1,25,26,Null,Null

**File**

Name,RNo,M,T

Raj,1,100,M3

Raj,1,200,M4
```

If i join table with File 
**Output** needed as

```
Name,RNo,M1,M2,M3,M4

Raj,1,25,26,100,200
```

As the data is getting from file i cannot get the data by query. here am unable to join the data

am getting data like

```
Name,RNo,M1,M2,M3,M4

Raj,1,25,26,100,NULL

Raj,1,25,26,NULL,200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation with `max`, `case` and `group by`:

```
select t1.name, t1.rno, t1.M1, t1.M2, 
    max(case when f.t = 'M3' then f.M end) M3,
    max(case when f.t = 'M4' then f.M end) M4
from table1 t1
    join file f on t1.name = f.name and t1.rno = f.rno
group by t1.name, t1.rno
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already reached this far , The easiest way to proceed would be use an Aggregator.

Assuming that the value of M3 and M4s are Numeric
1. first convert all the NULLs to zeroes.

2. Use an aggregator stage and group based on all other columns (sum(M3) and sum(M4)
3. That should ideally give you what you are looking for

Another way to do this would be using multiple look ups on the file.

1. Source stage would extracting data from the source table.
2. First Look up for M1 (look up condition would have all the keys AND T=M1) Get the value of M1 from the file save it in a new column called M1.
3. Then another look up for M2(look up condition would have all the keys AND T=M2). Get the value of M1 from the file save it in a new column called M1.
4. .... and so on for all the M columns that you would need. 
   So by the end of all looks ups ; if You are doing as expected - then you final output link should be the output that you were looking for

Both the steps have their positives and negatives.

Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

1) Read the sequential file and use pivot stage with option as Horizontal Pivoting to convert Rows into columns. Now the output will be 
Raj,1,100,200

2) Use a lookup stage with primary data coming from Step 1 and  reference data coming from Table and lookup based on RNO as key.

After step 2, output will be Raj, 1, 25, 26, 100, 200